# Expected Value of independent random variables with an ${\rm Exp}(\lambda)$ common distribution

Tags: probability

Question is:

> Jack is selling his house, and has decided to accept the first offer exceeding $k$. Assume that successive offers are independent random variables with common distribution $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$.
>
> a) Find the expected number of offers he will reject before he sells the house;
>
> b) Find the expected value of the offer he will accept.

**I have solved Part A as :**

$p = e^{-\lambda r}$

$P(N=n) = (1-p)^{n-1}p$

$E(N) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(N=n) = p \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}$

Eventually this will reduce down to $E(N) = \frac {1}{p} = e^{\lambda r}$

This should be correct.

**Part B :**

I am not sure how we go about finding the value of the actual offer that he will accept. I feel we have to find some conditional expectation but not sure. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The exponential distribution is memoryless: the conditional distribution of $X-k$ given $X>k$ coincides with the distribution of $X$ (you may check this property). That said, $$\mathrm{E}[X\mid X>k] = k + \mathrm{E}[X-k\mid X>k] =  k + \mathrm{E}[X].$$

Comment: Do you have X as the number of offers that occur before you accept one? This is what I used N for in part A

Comment: @ttucker34, $X$ is an offer (a random variable with exponential distribution).

Comment: So, after making this calculation, since E[X] is Exponential then E[X] would just equal (1/x) and the answer I am looking for would be k + (1/X)?

Comment: I mean  not X

Comment: Yes, it is $k +1/\lambda$.

Answer (score -2):

Can you see why this is the calculation?

$$
{\cal E}[x] = \frac{\int\limits_{x = x_0}^\infty x p(x)\ dx }{ \int\limits_{x = x_0}^\infty p(x)\ dx}
$$

[image]

The only conditions you must consider are those for $x>x_0$.

The only cases that contribute to your answer are those where the value is greater than some cutoff, $x_0$.  Consider this the relevant distribution.  The numerator is the expected value of $x$ from this distribution.  However, this is not a true distribution because it isn't normalized.  That's what the denominator accomplishes, where of course $p(x) \propto e^{-x}$.

Comment: No I do not. I know why the j = k + 1 since the offer is greater than k, so it needs to be k + 1 to infinity. But I do not understand the rest of the answer

Comment: Shouldn't these be integrals with index $x = k$ to $\infty$, rather than summations?  I thought the offer values were continuous random variables.

Comment: @BrianTung that is what I was thinking since the Exponential distribution is for continuous random variables and the geometric is for the discrete rvs

Comment: Can you explain what the p(x) is? And how I can calculate the final answer?

Comment: @ttucker34: I imagine $p(x)$ is the PDF of the offer distribution—in this case, $p(x) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$.  And $x_0 = k$.  David G Stork may have been a bit misled by using $k$ as a generally real value (as opposed to an integer, which it most commonly is).